# How do Cogs and belts work? / Cogs and belts in an ICAS exam

Tags: machining, pulleys, turbomachinery

[image]

---

Does the left red wheel turn in the same direction as the leftmost orange wheel?If so P and S go up? If not, Q and S go up?

My reasoning:

If so

1. Leftmost orange cc
2. Left red cc (by assumption)
3. Leftleast orange clock --> P goes up
4. Gray cc
5. Right least orange clock
6. Right most orange clock (similar to assumption)
7. Right red cc --> s goes up

If not

1. Leftmost orange cc
2. Left red clock
3. Leftleast orange cc --> Q goes up
4. Gray clock
5. Right least orange cc
6. Right most orange clock (similar to assumption)
7. Right red cc --> s goes up

Comment: This looks more like a GCSE (or earlier? Key Stage 3?) physics exam question to me, although googling "ICAS" gives me "The Institute of Chartered Accountants Scotland"... Not personally convinced this is a great fit for engineering.SE.

Comment: @AndyT migrate to physics SE please?

Comment: @AndyT If it's about http://manipal.edu/mu/lp/ICAS-International-engineering.html, then it was engineering - but the best place for it on  SE is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two wheels/pulleys/cogs are connected by a belt, when one of the wheels turns the other one turns in the same direction as the first wheel that turns.

When two cogs/gears are positioned so they are touching, when one cog is turned in one direction the other cog turns in the opposite direction.

So for your example:

1. The upper left yellow cog turns counter clockwise (ccw)
2. Because its connect to the red cog via a belt, the red cog also
   rotates ccw and the middle yellow cog turns clockwise (cw) causing
   weight P to rise.
3. Because the middle yellow cog rotates cw the black cog rotates the
   opposite direction, ccw. This causes the upper right yellow cog to
   turn cw.
4. The upper right yellow cog is connected to the lower right yellow
   cog via a belt, so the lower right yellow cog also turns cw.
5. The lower right yellow cog touches the lower right red cog which
   then turns the opposite direction, ccw.
6. This results in weight S being raised.